# Save my tasks data records from SQL Server to Outlook 2007 in VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation, outlook

Please help me by providing the code (VB.Net) to save all my tasks that are saved in Sql Server into Outlook.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interop : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168022(v=office.11).aspx

> **Summary:** Outlook provides a number of objects and methods for taking
>   advantage of its built-in
>   capabilities. This article illustrates
>   some of those to include
>   programmatically creating
>   appointments, retrieving unread
>   messages from the Inbox, and
>   retrieving contacts. (11 printed
>   pages)
>
> **Contents**
>
> - Introduction
> - Create an Appointment
> - Create a Meeting Request
> - Retrieve Unread Messages from the Inbox
> - Retrieve Contacts
> - Conclusion

Answer (score 0):

Try this add-on : [www.geniusconnect.com](http://www.geniusconnect.com)

- Link your Task folder to your table (GeniusConnect Config->Database->Assign Table)

To load your tasks manually:

- Select your folder and hit "Load All" from Toolbar/Riboon in Outlook 2010

To Auto Load:

- Go to Synchronize Schedule in GeniusConnect Config
- Enable auto sync
- Set direction direction to "Load All"